# Can't set headers after they are sent Node / Express

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, post

I am trying to post data from a form on the client side using jquery to a post route that sends data to an api in node / express.

I am getting the error Can't set headers after they are sent and I can't figure out why.

How can I fix this?

Client:

```
<input id="prospect-form" type="text" placeholder="Email Address" class="form-control" style="vertical-align: baseline; display:inline-block; background-color: white; border: none;" onClick="submitData()" />

<script charset="utf-8">
    var submitData = function() {
      var data = $("prospect-form").serialize();
      $.post("/prospect/" + data, function() {
        console.log("data sent");
      })
      .done(function() {
        console.log("data success");
      })
      .fail(function() {
        console.log("data failed");
      })
      .always(function() {
        console.log("data finished");
      })
    }
</script>
```

Express:

```
router.post('/prospect/:query', function(req, res) {
  var data = req.params.query;
  var options = {
    url: "https://prospect.io/api/public/v1/prospects",
    formData: data,
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "",
      "Content-Type": "application/vnd.api+json; charset=utf-8",
    }
  }

  function callback(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var info = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(info);
    }
  }

  request.post(options, callback) //post

  res.end()

}) //router post
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is simple.

I think  request.post(options, callback)  is an async function right?
When the code begin to executing res.end(), the function request.post is still executing as a separate thread.

That's why you have this multi thread issue. It's a common async error for node and express.

The solution is either use promise, async.js or async/await to make it become sync order.

Comment: Actually `request.post()` is not executing in another thread.  It is asynchronous, but networking operations in node.js use OS async networking calls and do not use additional threads.

Answer (score 0):

You should move your res.end() inside the callback function.

The updated could will be

```
router.post('/prospect/:query', function(req, res) {
  var data = req.params.query;
  var options = {
    url: "https://prospect.io/api/public/v1/prospects",
    formData: data,
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "",
      "Content-Type": "application/vnd.api+json; charset=utf-8",
    }
  }

  function callback(error, response, body) {
   if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var info = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(info);
   }
   res.end()
  }

  request.post(options, callback) //post

}) //router post
```